# Why UIBarButtonItem's foucs area smaller than prior in iOS11?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
[button sizeToFit];  
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];  
[button addTarget:self  
           action:@selector(tap)  
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

When i run in iOS 10 or prior version, I can touch outside this button's bounds more than 5-10px and trigger this action(tap).

But in new released iOS11, I can trigger action only touch inside the area.

How can I do like the performance in iOS10 or prior?
Is the new layout of new navigationItem lead to this question?

Comment: Actually, I regard the earlier behavior as a bug.

Comment: @matt I think the earlier behavior is more convinent for big screen or big finger 's user who may not accurate tap the button.

Comment: The problem was that bar button items could stop me from being able to tap buttons in my main view!

Answer (score 0):

I only set image to bar button item then adjust barbutton.imageInsets for iOS 11. For iOS lower than 11 I apply same code as yours.